# IPv6 with perl on windows not working

Tags: windows, perl, ipv6

cross-post http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=984750

(Possible duplicate of [perl windows IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348206/perl-windows-ipv6) )
I tried following sample example from : https://metacpan.org/module/IO::Socket::IP

```
use IO::Socket::IP -register;

my $sock = IO::Socket->new(
   Domain    => PF_INET6,
   LocalHost => "::1",
   Listen    => 1,
) or die "Cannot create socket - $@\n";

print "Created a socket of type " . ref($sock) . "\n";
```

It is giving output as : 
Cannot create socket - no address associated with nodename

I am using ActiveState perl 5.14.2 and have built IO::Socket::IP module on it.

Following is the ping result:

```
c:\>ping ::1

Pinging ::1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms

Ping statistics for ::1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

If I use the IPv4 style loopback address 127.0.0.1, the above code works well.
I am wondering what I am missing.

Update:

I just cleaned the perl setup and path, and freshly installed perl 5.14.2 from
http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads

and then I tried following simple code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Socket qw(getaddrinfo SOCK_STREAM AI_PASSIVE  );

my ( $err, @res ) = getaddrinfo( "::", 8086, {
    socktype => SOCK_STREAM,
    flags => AI_PASSIVE,
} );
die $err if $err;
```

it ended with following error:
no address associated with nodename at c:\IPv6.pl line 10.

But with 127.0.0.1 it returns proper value.

I am using windows 2008 R2 box, a same run on my another windows box also fails.

I just tried to trace this call in Socket.pm, and found that a "fake_getaddrinfo" is getting called instead of the real getaddrinfo. It seems the XSLoader was either not able to find/load getaddrinfo from Socket.dll or Socket.dll didn't at all have the getaddrinfo.
What could be the reason?

A similar code below using Socket6 works properly on the same setup:

```
use Socket;
use Socket6;

@res = getaddrinfo('::', 8086, AF_UNSPEC, SOCK_STREAM);

while(scalar(@res)>=5){

    ($family, $socktype, $proto, $saddr, $canonname, @res) = @res;
    ($host, $port) = getnameinfo($saddr, NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
    print ("\nhost= $host port = $port");
    socket(Socket_Handle, $family, $socktype, $proto) || next;
    bind(Socket_Handle,$saddr  )  || die "bind: $!";
    listen(Socket_Handle, 5) || die "listen: $!";

    ($host, $port) = getnameinfo($saddr, NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);
    print ("\nReady for connections \nhost= $host port = $port");
    $paddr = accept(Client, Socket_Handle);
}
```

So I can't even blame the setup or the system dlls. Is there an issue with perl's built-in IPv6 support for windows' activestate build?

Comment: The snippet works perfectly on Linux so this is probably a platform bug

Comment: I suspect the code above is not initializing an ipv6 socket address structure with the scope_id and flowspec fields set correctly. In C code, the typical way to bind to ::1 is to call getifaddrs() and enumerate for the adapter with ::1 as IP or "lo" as the adapter name. Then use the ifaddrs->ifa_addr as the socket address to bind to. I have no idea if perl has a way to do this.

Comment: Have you permitted this socket through windows firewall?

Comment: @anttix : Amazingly the same code snippet works very nice on a linux box for me as well!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [vinsworldcom on perlmonks.org](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=984917), to make use of IPv6 sockets you do need to have the `Socket6` module installed. As soon as you'd install this via cpan, the code snippet will work fine.